# Jquery Clone element Style

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clone a specific section of a div `style="background-color:<?php echo $mg ?>;"`

So what I want to happen is when I click a specific button it clones just the style part of the div.

At the moment I am getting this error `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).attr(...).clone is not a function`

Here is an example of what I currently have:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".mapei-grout-color").click(function() {
    $(this).attr('style').clone(true, true).appendTo('#the-grid');
    var $this = $(".grout-tab");
    if ($this.hasClass("clicked-once")) {
      $this.removeClass("clicked-once");
      $(".mapei").slideUp();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: you want the style of the button to be extracted out of it?

Comment: Yes when that element is clicked it then clones the inline style and places it where I want. Everything else I know how to do I just don't know how to clone a specific piece of a div in this case it's inline style.

Comment: I unable to understand what you want really, but that may help you  **$(selector).attr('style')**. that return a inline style of specific div.

Comment: Updated my question to show what I currently have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, when you click on one button, it takes the style of that button and clones it to the other button.

```js
$('#style').on('click',function(){
     document.getElementById('clone').setAttribute('style',this.getAttribute('style'));

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button style="background-color:blue" id="style">Click Here</button>
<button  id="clone">Clone</button>
```

Comment: Using jquery will reduce code to : `$('#clone').attr('style',$(this).attr('style'));`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the Jquery: [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to get a specific attribute.

For example:

```
$('div').attr('style')
```

Check [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k8qj0cn7/) to see a live example

**EDIT:**

To use this for your clone, you could do something like this:

```
$(this).clone().attr('style', $(this).attr('style')).appendTo('#the-grid');
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y8ffedn6/) for a live example.

Comment: Hi Nanashi, That didn't quite do it what's happened is its just taking the full div and putting it inside #the-grid instead of just take the style attribute and adding it to #the-grid

Answer (score 0):

Answer to your comment over here, I think I overlooked what you need exactly.

http://jsbin.com/gezafilado/edit?html,output

**clone(true)** will copy style attribute as well as all the other props of node.

You're doing the wrong move in your code - 
.attr('style') returns a **string**, not an **element**.
And I think you want to append cloned node to the grid.

so, instead of:

```
$(this).attr('style').clone(true, true).appendTo('#the-grid');
```

you need this:

```
$(this).clone(true).appendTo('#the-grid').attr("style", "Your new styles here");
```

or if you want to merge styles from original object with new ones:

```
var $elem = $(this).clone(true).appendTo('#the-grid');
var style = $elem.attr("style") + "Your new styles here";
$elem.attr("style", style);
```

Hope this helps and I gotcha the case.

Comment: So if im not using clone how can I just assign the style to it

Comment: Same thing again instead of adding the inline style for background color to the div to #the-grid it just puts the entire div inside of #the-grid